# R:Subsetting data frame by factor

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

assume we have the following data frame

```
foo
  k h=1 h=2 h=3
1 3   3   6   9
2 2   2   5   8
3 1   1   4   7
```

with

```
str(check)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ k  : Factor w/ 3 levels "3","2","1": 1 2 3
 $ h=1: int  3 2 1
 $ h=2: int  6 5 4
 $ h=3: int  9 8 7
```

How can I subset my dataframe based on the factor of `k`? For instance, to get only the row for k=3 or all rows k<3. I tried working with `subet(foo, k=3)` but it doesn't work. I also tried to convert the column k to numeric, but then my data.frame loses its order. It's important that the data is of descending order with regard to k (so 3, 2, 1)

Comment: `k` is a factor (categorical variable) but not an ordered factor (ordinal variable) so inequalities make no sense. Maybe use `k = ordered(3:1, levels=1:3)` or similar instead. Then `k == "3"; k < "3"` make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Bracket notation should be able to subset on factors without any problems:

```
# Returns all rows of foo where k == '3'
foo[foo$k == '3',]
```

Two possible problems with what you did before:

1) `subset(foo, k=3)` should be `subset(foo, k==3)`, don't confuse the equality operator (`==`) with the assignment operator (`=`)

2) Since you're comparing with the actual level of your factor, you should check for equality with the character `'3'` instead of the numeric `3`. You can see in the output from `str()` that k's levels are `"3","2","1"`, with quotes, whereas the integers for the other variables are shown without quotes `3 2 1`